# Transferring syntax to SAS EG and integrating prompts

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I've used this forum to gather information on creating and using prompts in SAS EG tasks and queries. However, I can't seem to transfer my own syntax from Base SAS, incorporate/reference prompts/macros I've created, and get it to work.

Currently, everytime I reference a prompt in my own program (rather than one generated by point-click selections in SAS EG) the log tells me SAS can't resolve the macro reference.

How can I transfer my own program into SAS EG and then integrate the prompts?

Example code I used to develop test data set:

```
data work.testscores;
    input Gender $ 1-6 SATScore 8-11 IDNumber 13-20;
    datalines;
Male   1170 61469897
Female 1090 33081197
Male   1240 68137597
Female 1490  9589297
Male   1200 93891897
Female 1080 26212897
Male   1050  8945097
Female 1200 51799397
Male   1600 39196697
;
run;
```

/*created Genders prompt in the prompt manager using gender variable*/

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE table WORK.testscores2 as
        SELECT &Genders, SATScore
    FROM WORK.TESTSCORES
;
QUIT;
```

Log:

```
102        PROC SQL;
103           CREATE TABLE WORK.TESTSCORES2 AS
104           SELECT &Genders
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference GENDERS not resolved.
104           SELECT &Genders
                     _
                     22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, 
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, BTRIM, INPUT, PUT, 
              SUBSTRING, USER.  

105              FROM WORK.TESTSCORES;
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
106        QUIT;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Thanks,A

Comment: Can you provide examples of the code and log? Basically, there is no difference how macrovariable was created  - by SAS code or EG Prompt Manager. So possibly there are some issues in code.

Comment: I assume, you assigned this prompt to your program, so that when you run it, prompt window pops up and you enter desired value. What value do you enter?

Comment: Dmitry I was using it simply select the gender column. Therefore I assign the prompt to the testscores dataset, and select a variable type and load the gender variable (although I call the macro var 'Genders'. When I run the program the prompt box does not appear.

Comment: I wonder, how did you assign prompt to dataset? It can be assigned to the task only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments of the topic starter, it looks like there is some misunderstanding how prompts in EG work. It's not a tool for assigning value to some  macrovariable BEFORE running your program. 'Prompt' implies that the program prompts you to enter the value DURING the program running. But for that, you have to assign your prompt to coressponding program, so that when you run this particular program SAS would envoke this particular prompt. For that: `right click on the task -> Properties -> Prompts -> Add`.

Comment: I agree I must have misunderstood to be this stuck.

Comment: But thank you, that last bit about the right-click has got the prompt popping up!

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand what you want to achieve by your code. Do you want select just male or female SAT-scores based on the value of the macro variable you set in the prompt?

```
proc sql;
    create table work.testscores2 as
        select gender, satscore
            from work.testscores
                where gender = &genders.;
/* Where the value of &genders is either 'Male' or 'Female' */
quit;
```

Comment: Apologies - I did not want to select only male or female, I was just writing a simple sql to select the gender column. Even if I do your version, create a prompt for specifying the values of gender, it does not work and returns the same error. I also note that you have a full stop after your macro variable - I'm not sure why. I don't do that in SAS Base, I tried this also and it still returned the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To use a macro variable created in a prompt, you need to check the box "Use prompt value throughout project".

[image: Prompt]

Comment: Thanks Joe, but this does not seem to resolve the problem. I believe this is for when you want the prompt to reappear if the macro variable is referenced more than once in the program - at this point I am only referencing it once.

Comment: That checkbox allows you to access the macro variable at any point in your code.  For example, if you have a prompt with name "Period", if you check this box, the value of the prompt is accessible in your program through `&period.` (a macro variable).  If you don't check that, you cannot access it in code.  It has nothing to do with when the prompt appears.

Comment: Based on your code provided, I think both my answer and Havard's answer are needed.  You can't use &Genders. where you do if it's supposed to contain "Male"; that's the column name, not the data.  But if &Genders is not being resolved, it's because you didn't check that box.

Comment: Thanks Joe - I appreciate your input - I was trying to simply select the Gender column, not a specify value in that column. Even if I select the option you suggest the code still does not work.  Like Havard, you have a full stop after your macro variable - why is this? Although doing this does not seem to make my code work.

Comment: `&macrovar.` is technically the definition of a macro variable.  The period/full stop is the ending delimiter.  It's optional, if some other invalid character (like a space) appears; but if you have, say, `&myvar_someothertext` and mean for `&myvar` to be the variable, the _ is a legal macro character - so `&myvar._someothertext` is needed.

Comment: If you're intending to use the word "Gender" as the value of your prompt, and the word "Gender" is the value of the prompt, then your code is fine so long as you named the prompt "Genders" and selected "Use prompt value throughout project".  Perhaps you need to explain further the section "Created Genders through prompt manager."

Comment: Thanks - but it still doesn't seem to work! I must be missing something really obvious here. The code works fine when I run it in Base SAS. I will do it again now and document my steps for you.

Comment: What are you doing?  You need to explain further how you're doing this.  Did you create a prompt the same as my picture above?  What do you mean, created it *from* a variable?

Comment: I run my code to create testscores data set. I go to prompt manager, click add, type Gender, tick require non-blank, tick use prompt throughout. Select prompt type = variable, specify character variables and load values from the testscores data set, select gender and click OK.